# How to change a textview in NavigationView app:headerLayout?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.android

```C#
<android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:id="@+id/nav_view"
        app:headerLayout="@layout/drawer_header"
        app:menu="@menu/navmenu" />
drawer_header

<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="120dp"
    android:background="#FFFFFF">
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="60dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true">
        <FFImageLoading.Views.ImageViewAsync
            android:id="@+id/imgThunbailUser"
            android:layout_width="80dp"
            android:layout_height="80dp" />
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/txtUsername"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
            android:textColor="#ffffff"
            android:text="Music store"
            android:textSize="18dp" />
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/txtlast_modified"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textColor="#ffffff"
            android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:text="SoundCloud"
            android:textSize="14dp"
            android:textStyle="normal" />
    </LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

MainActivity

```
txtUsername = FindViewById<TextView> (Resource.Id.txtUsername);
textUsername.text="bcdf";
```

I have tried it but I got error at textUsername. I'm making a login. I need load a image, textview to drawer_header.How to change a textview in NavigationView app:headerLayout?

Answer (score 0):

You must first get a reference to the headerview from your navigation view. 
Then you can use that reference to get the textview within the headerview, something like this:

```
var navigationView = FindViewById<NavigationView>(Resource.Id.nav_view);
var headerView = navigationView.GetHeaderView(0)
var txtUsername = x.FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.txtUsername);
```